# Java web browser

Tags: java, webkit, browser

I have searched for weeks for something like library or project or something that can make my Java Application display whole website like real web browser. I found lobo, cobra, but all of them already dead. I used SWT(which is native) and it went not well with MAC.

How can i achieve this? Library or something please

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MozSwing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing/) to embed the Firefox for example.

Comment: Is it any tutorial for it?

Comment: after i run the demo of MozSwing i get this error: "Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform". Doesn't it support 64 bit machine??

Comment: If you are using a 32bit JVM you also need a 32bit Firefox, and vice versa. Type "java -version" in a console to show your jvm version, and download the appropriate Firefox version.

Comment: my JVM is 64-bit version. What do you mean "appropriate Firefox version"? mean i have to download the 64-bit version? but i think my firefox is already 64-bit. EDIT: wait, i'm sorry. my firefox isn't 64. I'll try download and run it again.